# Why would an extra column (unnamed: 0) appear after saving the df and then reading it through pd.read_csv?

Tags: pandas

My code to save the df is:

```
fdi_out_vdem.to_csv("fdi_out_vdem.csv")
```

To read the df into python is :

```
fdi_out_vdem = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/asus/Desktop/classen/fdi_out_vdem.csv")
```

The df:

| Unnamed: 0 | country_name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Spain | 190 |
| 2 | Spain | 311 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your df has two columns, but also an index with "0" and "1". When writing it to csv it looks like this:

```
,country_name,value
0,Spain,190
1,Spain,311
```

When importing it with pandas you it is considered as df with 3 columns (and the first has no name)

You have two possibilities here:
Save it without index column:

```
df.to_csv("fdi_out_vdem.csv", index=False)

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/asus/Desktop/classen/fdi_out_vdem.csv")
```

or save it with index column and define an index col when reading it with `pd.read_csv`

```
df.to_csv("fdi_out_vdem.csv")

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/asus/Desktop/classen/fdi_out_vdem.csv", index_col=[0])
```

**UPDATE**
As recommended by @ouroboros1 in the comments you could also name your index before saving it to csv, so you can define the index column by using that name

```
df.index.name = "index"
df.to_csv("fdi_out_vdem.csv")

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/asus/Desktop/classen/fdi_out_vdem.csv", index_col="index")
```

Comment: For clarity's sake, you could also give your index a name. E.g. `df.index.name = 'index'`.  Then after writing the `df` to a csv (with default `index=True` of course), you can refer to the column by using the name. So: `df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/asus/Desktop/classen/fdi_out_vdem.csv", index_col='index')`.

Comment: @ouroboros1 good call. I will update my answer with your additional input.

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass the parameter `index_col=[0]` to [**`pandas.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) :

```
fdi_out_vdem = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/asus/Desktop/classen/fdi_out_vdem.csv", index_col=[0])
```

Or even better, get rid of the index at the beginning when calling [**`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
fdi_out_vdem.to_csv("fdi_out_vdem.csv", index=False)
```